# Instantiate moving original object

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I'm very new at Unity and I can not figure this out. I have a ball when it drops and collides with the bottom of the screen it will create another ball randomly on the screen.   This process will continue until the designated maximum number of balls are on the screen. It basically works but when the first ball hits the bottom and generates a new ball the original ball appears to be recreated or moved back up on the screen in a random position. I want the ball just to keep bouncing and creating new balls.

here is the relevant code.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.name == "tile" && balls < maxBalls )
     {
        balls = balls + 1;
        randomX = Random.Range(-3, 4);
        randomY = Random.Range(-3, 4);
        transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, transform.position.z);
        Instantiate(ball, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        NumberofBalls();

     }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it moves the original ball is because of this line:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, transform.position.z);
```

This sets the position of the current object.

If you want to just spawn new objects at random positions, you should do this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "tile" && balls < maxBalls )
    {
        balls = balls + 1;
        randomX = Random.Range(-3, 4);
        randomY = Random.Range(-3, 4);
        Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(randomX, randomY, transform.position.z);
        Instantiate(ball, newPosition, transform.rotation);
        NumberofBalls();
    }
}
```

[image: working- first ball]

[image: not working - missing game object (should point to prefab)]

Comment: wow, thanks, that fixed that...if not to much to ask when the "new" balls are created and the hit the bottom they don't create new balls can you help me with that?

Comment: Does the prefab you're instantiating from have the same script attached to it?

Comment: what I've found is when the new ball is created using the prefab the newly created ball is missing the prefab pointer to create the next ball. i'll try and add a picture.

Comment: Are you sure the prefab has the reference set and not just the first ball?

Comment: far as i know it did...i changed up my app, i tied the script to the bottom tile and then added the ball prefab to the script and that seems to have fixed it...thanks for your help